# Add "Black right-pointing pointer" HTML entity in css content

Tags: html, css, html-entities

I'm trying to add a "Black right-pointing pointer" html entity into my css `:after` content but to no avail.

I know you need to use a unicode value but I can't find one that works for this. This is the unicode number `U+25BA` and this is the HTML code `&#9658;`

Answer (score 3):

You should use a backslash and a hex code:

```
i:after {
    content: "\25ba";
}
```

Obviously, this character must be present in the font used. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c29VS/1/

Comment: Alternatively, you can enter the character as such: `content: "►"`. You need to use UTF-8 and declare it properly for this to work, but that should be done anyway.